# afterSave in Parse cloud code will not save new userId into another class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am attempting to save the username and userId from the User class when a user registers into another class, but for some reason the afterSave handler won't save any information. The code I am using currently is:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {

  // Check if the User is newly created

  if (!request.object.existed()) {
    // Set default values

    var RunnerClass =  Parse.Object.extend("Runner");
    var runner =  new RunnerClass;
    runner.set("username", request.object.get("username"));
    runner.set("userId", request.object.id);


    runner.save(null, {
        success: function(runner) { 
                   response.success(runner);
                 },
        error: function(error) {
                 response.error(error);
               }
     });

  } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line

```
var runner =  new RunnerClass;
```

with

```
var runner =  new RunnerClass();
```

Also response.success() in the last line should be removed if you're expecting the returned response with runner object.

Comment: changed but it still did not make a new entry into the Runner Class

Comment: are you sure it is hitting inside the loop? what is the message showing up on the log?

Comment: I don't think it is hitting the loop I attempted console.log(request.object.id) and nothing appeared in Xcode

Comment: Look at the logs here. https://parse.com/apps/YOUR_APP_NAME/cloud_code/log . Replace with your app name

Comment: ok I get an error message of  Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'error' of undefined
    at Object.runner.save.error (main.js:66:14)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `response.success()` at the end of the function.

The [CloudCode guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-network-requests) says:

> In general, you should wait for all network requests to finish before calling `success`

The `runner.save` function is asynchronous, so the call at the end of the function is getting called before it's execution terminates, and the Parse Cloud Runtime kills the save request.

Comment: that has been removed but still nothing